# Video on my site won't play in chrome. If you click on another link and go back, than it plays just fine

Tags: wordpress, video, video-streaming, html5-video, mp4

Very strange. I uploaded the video in all three formats: .mp4, .ogv & .webm. It just won't play in chrome. In Safari and Firefox, it works just fine. The strange part is: it used to work fine until yesterday and it still works fine if you click on another link on my site and then go back.

I'm using the Salient theme on WordPress.

[Link to the site](https://danielkort.com/homepage-en/)

Does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to Chrome's new autoplay policy - it will not autoplay videos on first load unless the video is muted. Can you add 'muted' to the video attributes?

Source: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Edit: there should be a 'Mute Video' option in the Video Background settings of your row.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to implement it. It's a header video, not a row unfortunately...

Comment: Ah, damn. In that case, you'll have to copy the entire `nectar_slider_display()` function from the theme and put that in your own child theme's functions.php, and edit the `<video>` output to include `muted`.

Comment: I just noticed you're not using a child theme (by the looks of it, anyway). I would take a look at this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/196703/how-do-i-make-my-child-theme-re-apply-the-settings-that-were-customised-when-its/198127#198127 so you can switch to a child theme without losing all of your theme customisations.

Comment: To check that this is the issue however, you could just go ahead and change the `nectar_slider_display()` function directly in the theme's functions.php, however you'll have to do this every time you update the Salient theme if you don't want to create a child theme.

Comment: Youre the F***IN BEST MAN!! It worked! I edited the functions.php (for the first time) after changing 3 php files i finally got the right one.

Comment: Yeah you're right, but I have to finish the site till Thursday, so I'll take care of the child theme thing when I have the time.

Thank you!!

Comment: No problem - the theme developers really should have fixed that themselves by now!